# Is it possible to create an Excel file via Flash / ActionScript?

Tags: flash, excel, actionscript, createfile

Is it possible to make an actionscript/flash function that takes values and creates an excel file or edit an excel file?

Excel creation is killing the CPU and memory via phpexcel class. I thought Why not use client's CPU...

Comment: The reason why not is because then you have to use the server's bandwidth in the upload. But you might find that simply saving comma- or tab- delimited data (using either the client or the server) will yeild a file that can be opened in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Flash 10 & above has a feature of saving data to client machines directly as image files. But I doubt that is irrelevant for now.

Flash cannot launch excel or generate an excel file. However, You may try this:

- Create an xml file which can be read by Excel (To see how excel
  generated file looks like save an excel doc as xml spreadsheet).
- Upload the xml data to the server (little server side scripting needed)
- Generate a download link for the user to download the data.

Although it seems to be an alternative, I doubt if it's even worth the work to send the data to and fro, so much as above.

Answer (score 0):

Please see given below Link for your answer:

as3xls:

Some time ago I was working on a little project for which I wanted to read and write Excel files in Flex. I Googled hither and yon but sadly I could only find a sample someone tossed out there sans code. So, I put together a little package to read and write Excel files. So far it supports reading text, numbers, formulas, and dates from Excel version 2.x-2003 and writing text, numbers, and dates. Formulas also update to reflect changes in cells they reference.

The API is intended to be straightforward and easy to use. There are some samples to play with and the obligatory ASdocs.

[Click Here](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/wiki/Tutorial)

Comment: He's looking for a Flash solution: does this work with Flash without adjustments?

Comment: Yes, This is ActionScript 3.0 Code and We can develop with Flash CS4 or any other higher version. 
Another way we can develop one small widget in Flex and load compiled swf (Flex application widget) in the flash application as an external swf file. it will work in both way....

Comment: The fact that is AS3 is not important: AS3 for Flash lacks things like ArrayCollection, so if that code uses it and you have to compile from the Flash IDE, it will probably throw some error.